# Not able to understand the output for dictionary comprehension in python

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

the output for the code:

```
dict={k:v for k in range(1,4)  for v in range(1,3) }
print(dict)
```

out put is:

```
{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2}
```

but thought the output should be:

```
{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1}
```

why is it taking 2 for the value of v.

Comment: It might be illustrative to run the same thing as a list comprehension, to see what you are actually feeding into the dictionary: `[(k, v) for k in range(1, 4) for v in range(1, 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

Python lets you use the same key multiple times in a dictionary comprehension, but obviously the final dictionary can only contain the key once. The associated value is the *last* one you specified, as per the [Python reference manual, 6.2.7 Dictionary Displays](https://docs.python.org/3.12/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

> When the comprehension is run, the resulting key and value elements are inserted in the new dictionary in the order they are produced.